# php curl cookie not registering

Tags: php, curl

I've been playing with [this](http://www.codercaste.com/2009/12/15/use-curl-with-php-to-handle-http-requests-and-create-useful-scripts/) curl facebook login script for a while just trying to get to grips with some of the features in curl, but it seems that I can not get the cookies to register:

**php script**

```
     function facebookLogin(){
        $login_email = 'email';
        $login_pass = 'pass';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.facebook.com/login.php');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'email='.urlencode($login_email).'&pass='.urlencode($login_pass).'&login=Login');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.facebook.com");
        $page = curl_exec($ch);
        echo $page;
    }
```

I have a text file called cookies.txt which is in the same directory as the script, but after running this script nothing is written into the file and therefore no cookies are created, this is a big issue when trying to explore other web pages on the same website as you have to keep logging in.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it turns out it is registered even if the cookies.txt file is empty but you need to make sure you call this file when you try to explore other parts of the site e.g.

```
function facebookGoToMessages(){
    facebookLogin();

    $ch = curl_init ("http://www.facebook.com/messages");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt"); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.facebook.com");
    $page = curl_exec ($ch);
    echo $page; 
}
```